# VScode Exit with code=3 when uploading sketch

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

I am starting to use VScode for my arduino coding with XIAO nRF52840. I have Arduino for VS Code installed.
When I upload code (main.ino), I get following code.

```
[Starting] Uploading sketch 'main\main.ino'
[Warning] Output path is not specified. Unable to reuse previously compiled files. Build will be slower. See README.
Loading configuration...
Initialising packages...
Preparing boards...
Error: nrf52: Unknown architecture
[Warning] Failed to generate IntelliSense configuration.
[Error] Uploading sketch 'main\main.ino': Exit with code=3
```

it happens with any code. It works with Arduino IDE without any problem. Assuming something is wrong in a setting.

```
"arduino.ignoreBoards": [
],
"arduino.path": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino",
"arduino.commandPath": "arduino_debug.exe",
"arduino.logLevel": "info",
"arduino.enableUSBDetection": true,
"arduino.disableTestingOpen": false,
"arduino.skipHeaderProvider": false,
"arduino.additionalUrls": [
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VSChina/azureiotdevkit_tools/master/package_azureboard_index.json,http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json,https://files.seeedstudio.com/arduino/package_seeeduino_boards_index.json",
],
"arduino.defaultBaudRate": 9600,
```

Can someone figureoit what is the problem?

Comment: `Error: nrf52: Unknown architecture`

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: nrf52 :Unknown architecture
```

Make sure that you are choosing the right architecture in Vscode it's apparent that you are not using the correct architecture for your micro Controller

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GFYo.png

If you are using PlatformIO you select the board when you create project or

you can add the new board as env variables

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzOTL.png